# Why are these two angles the same?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, geometry, approximations

[image]

I can't find no similar or other relations between the two triangles, the two right triangles.

However, if I look at it this way, the two triangles are indeed similar. But then this is a whole different situation.
[image]

Following @Kevin Zhou's instruction, I drew this: (I still couldn't get my conclusion.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This calculation assumes that the other screen is very far away, that is, $y \ll D$. So redraw your diagram so that the green line is very nearly horizontal, and you'll get the conclusion.

Comment: But then if I make two right triangles, it's something completely different.?

Comment: I edited in a picture I drew according to your description, is that right?